# Timestamp unintentionally showing when using video.js and BigVideo

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, video.js

I am using BigVideo.js and video.js to play a clip in the background of my loading page. At the start, when the page loads in Chrome, [you can see a timestamp for a split second](http://creativebyt.es/sandbox/stackoverflow.png) and then it fades away. This is unintentional and it should be removed.

Here is a the link to the [website](http://creativebyt.es) where you can view the source. I have attempted to correct this by using `$(window).load(function ()`, but that does not seem to help.

Here is the main code for the displaying the clip, which is at the bottom of my home page.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!--<script src=jquery-ui.min.js></script>-->
<!-- NOT SURE IF THIS IS NEEDED. I REMOVED IT BECAUSE IT WAS SLOWING DOWN THE SITE.-->
<script src=video.js></script>
<script src=bigvideo.js></script>
<script>
    if (/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
        var BV = new $.BigVideo();
        BV.init();
        BV.show('creative-bytes.png');
    } else {
        if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1) {
            $(function () {
                var BV = new $.BigVideo({
                    useFlashForFirefox: false
                });
                BV.init();
                BV.show('test.ogv', {
                    ambient: true
                });
            });
        } else {
            $(function () {
                var BV = new $.BigVideo({
                    useFlashForFirefox: false
                });
                BV.init();
                BV.show('test.mp4', {
                    ambient: true
                });
            });
        }
    }
</script>
<script>
    $(window).load(function () {
        $(document.body).fadeIn(1000);
    });
</script>
```

[image: Landing page screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to your CSS:

```
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-progress-control,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-time-controls,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-time-divider,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-captions-button,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-mute-control,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-volume-control,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-fullscreen-control {
    display: none;  /* Hide Video.js statistics */
}
```

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks so much ^_^.